# Rotate with Euler angles in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics, animation, rotation

I need to rotate with the Euler angle sequence:

1. Yaw by $\psi$ around $z$
2. Pitch by $\theta$ around $y'$
3. Roll by $\phi$ around $x''$

I know of `Rotate[]` in Mathematica, but I do not see an Euler angle option for it. I need to eventually have something like the pseudo-code below:

```
Graphics3D[Translate[Rotate[object3D,psi,theta,phi],{x,y,z}]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you search the documentation for "Euler angles"? Did it come up with something?  Maybe "rotation"?  Learning to the use the docs is a valuable skill.

Comment: @chuy Thanks, I found the answer from documentation.

Comment: As a historical note: the old ``Geometry`Rotations` `` package used to use Euler angles instead of pitch-roll-yaw. But as noted by @chuy, the conversion formulae are in fact in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Here is the source code:

```
(* Create the Euler rotation matrix *)
yawRotationInv = RotationTransform[ψ, {0, 0, 1}];
pitchRotationInv = RotationTransform[θ, {0, 1, 0}];
rollRotationInv = RotationTransform[ϕ, {1, 0, 0}];
EulerRotate[ϕ_, θ_, ψ_] = Composition[yawRotationInv, pitchRotationInv, rollRotationInv];

Manipulate[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[],
EulerRotate[ϕ, θ, ψ]]}], {ϕ, 0, 
Pi/2}, {θ, 0, Pi/2}, {ψ, 0, Pi/2}]
```